# Show, for every connected graph G of order 6 with four independent vertices, that either α(G)=5 or α′(G) ≥ 2.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

Show, for every connected graph G of order 6 with four independent vertices, that either α(G)=5 or α′(G) ≥ 2.

a(G) stands for vertex independent number (max number of vertices such that no two vertices are adjacent in graph G)
         a'(G) stands for edge independent number (max number of edges no two which are adjacent in graph G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{S=a,b,c,d\}$ be an independent set of size 4 and let $u,v$ be the remaining vertices. If $\alpha(G)=5$, then we are done, otherwise there must be an edge from $u$ to $S$ and an edge from $v$ to $S$.

If $u,v$ are not adjacent and further if there's only one such edge for $u$ and one such edge for $v$ and both are to the same vertex, say $a$, then, $\{b,c,d,u,v\}$ is an independent set of size 5.

Otherwise, if there's an edge from $u$ to $a$ and an edge from $v$ to $b$, then we get two disjoint edges and we get $\alpha'(G) \geq 2$.

Finally, if $u$ and $v$ are adjacent and both have edges only to the same vertex, say $a$, then the graph is not connected, which contradicts the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a graph of order $6$ with no isolated vertices, and if $G$ has four independent vertices, then $\alpha(G)=5$ or $\alpha'(G)=2.$

**Proof.** Let $u,v_1,v_2,v_3$ be four independent vertices, and let $x,y$ be the other two vertices. Clearly $\alpha(G)\le5$ (since there are no isolated vertices), and $\alpha'(G)\le2$ (since every edge has at least one endpoint in $\{x,y\}$). It remains to show that $\alpha(G)\ge5$ or $\alpha'(G)\ge2.$

Since the vertex $u$ is not isolated, it's joined to $x$ or $y$; without loss of generality, assume there is an edge $ux.$

If any of the edges $v_i$ is joined to $y,$ then $ux,v_iy$ are independent edges; thus we may assume that the vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are joined to $x$ but not to $y.$

Now, if $u$ is joined to $y,$ then $uy,v_1x$ are independent edges; otherwise, $u,v_1,v_2,v_3,y$ are five independent vertices.